# In which order should I install python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, installation, pycharm

I am starting two courses, one in my university which will be teaching on Python 2.7.12 and another online course that will be on Python 3.5.2.

In which order and how should I install python for it?
If I need to move from one version to another then how should I do it?
How to configure Pycharm to run both versions and select my desired version while running the code?
Which installation would be better Python official release or Anaconda?

I am on 64 bit Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Have you Googled how to set up independent installations of Python? It sounds like you want help with lots of details in setting up your development environment, which is out of scope for this site.

Comment: Use anaconda, it manages things better.

Comment: The order doesn't matter, make sure you create `virtualenv` for your projects and be sure to specify the correct python when you create them. Always take the official release unless the course allows Anaconda, that way you might not run into incompatibility issues.